# How can i spatially add text to feature in argis 10?

Tags: attribute-joins, arcgis-10.0

I have alot of text that write with drawing tools and same feature . i want to find a method to add texts to features spatially like spatial join for feature to feature . is there any method to add these texts?
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details and perhaps an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one piece of text per feature you should add a field to the attribute table as opposed to using text boxes.  If you go with this method you don't have to select text boxes individually, you can use the Select By Location or Select By Attributes tools in the file menu.

[image]
[image]

Comment: your method does not work . i have to add field in attribute and manually type text for features.select by location or select by attribute are selection tools .

Comment: If you use the select by location or attribute tools, paired with the 'Show only selected layer's' option you can change them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether this works for you or not. but it can helpful to check out **Update Annotation Feature Class (Data Management)** [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002t000000).

> Summary
>
> Updates the input annotation feature class with text attribute fields
>   and optionally populates the value of each new field for every feature
>   in the feature class.

Example:

```
# Name: UpdateAnnotation_Example.py
# Description: Use UpdateAnnotation to update ArcGIS 8.3 annotation feature classes
# to ArcGIS 9.0
# Author: ESRI

# import system modules 
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
# User input geodatabase location - eg. C:/data/anno83.mdb
env.workspace = raw_input('Annotation data location: ')

# Create list of annotation feature classes within the geodatabase
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "ANNOTATION")

# Loop through the feature classes and update
for fc in fcList:
    try:
        # Process: Update the annotation feature classes
        print "Updating " + fc + "..."
        arcpy.UpdateAnnotation_management(fc, "POPULATE")
    except:
        # If an error occurred while running a tool print the messages
        print arcpy.GetMessages()

print "Update of annotation feature classes in " + env.workspace + " complete"
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: i'd like to solve it without programming .